# Excel mouse cursor disappears after activewindow.freezepanes

Tags: excel, vba, mouse, freeze, cursor-position

I am conducting some Excel VBA screen styling. After manipulating a "header" for my user worksheet. I place my cursor on cell A4 and freeze the top three rows.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A4").Select
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
ActiveSheet.Range("A18").Select   'cursor disappears
```

Then the VBA code ends and the user has control of the sheet again. At this point, the mouse cell cursor disappears for every cell below the freeze line.

Some cases:

- If I click on cell K2, I can see the cell cursor.
- But, If I click on K16 or D10 or any cell below the freeze line, the cursor is invisible.
- If I click on K2 I see the cursor, but if I arrow down passing under the freeze line, the cursor disappears at row 4 and below.

There are several ways I can fix this but none of them are good solutions:

- If I click into another application (like this browser session typing this question), then click back to Excel, the cursor reappears below the freeze line.
- If I click my Windows Start button to show the Start menu, then click back into Excel, the cursor reappears below the freeze line.
- Basically, any mouse action that takes focus away from Excel, then clicking back into Excel returns the cursor appearance below the freeze line.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0):

What if you add

```
ActiveSheet.Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("A8").Select
```

When I ran your code on my sheet, my cursor didn't disappear so I am not sure.  Are you running that code off of a button or right the the developer console?

Comment: Hi yes I'm running the code off a button. the activesheet.activate did not change the condition. I did find after more testing on the first button click, the cursor does not disappear. But on the second button click it disappears thereafter.

Comment: oh... it's the same code, same button. Just clicking the button once when Excel is first opened. Then clicking it again. I saw th ecode run on another user's desktop. The hidden cell cursor doesn't happen. I'll probably just give up on this. I have much other work to do. Especially since it only seems to be my computer.